# Java: is this way of finding the maximum value in an integer array correct?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to find the highest value in an array of integers. I'd prefer not to use doubles anywhere.

```
public static int findMax(int...vals) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int d: vals) {
        if (d > max) max = d;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Depends. What should happen when no elements are passed?

Comment: I always want to pass elements when I call this method! But when none are passed nothing happens I guess.

Comment: Declared with `findMax(int...vals)`, it is possible to call it with no elements. If you want to make it compulsory to have at least one element, you can modify to `findMax(int val1, int...vals)`: this the caller needs to give a `val1`, that you can use as initialization. If you keep the same signature of `findMax(int...vals)`, *But when none are passed nothing happens I guess*: it doesn't work like this, you need to tell the compiler what should happen; the method has to return something, even when no elements are passed (or it can throw an exception, but you need to tell what must happen).

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation. Can the rest of the code be improved too, or is it ok?

Comment: This question might be better suited on [codereview.se] - but apart from that, your code is (with the advice by @Tunaki) pretty solid and it should work as expected.

Comment: `return IntStream.of(vals).max();`

Answer (score 0):

What about using Integer wrapper instead of primitives...

the best part is that you can use collections and efficiently get the max

```
public static int findMax(Integer[] vals) {

   return Collections.max(Arrays.asList(vals));
}
```

or

```
 public static int findMax(int[] vals) {
    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();    
    for (int d: vals) {
        l.add(d);
    }

    return Collections.max(l);
 }
```

Comment: Why would you use wrapper objects when you can work with primitive types? Note that this throws an exception when the array is empty, which might not be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to initialize max with the first value, throwing an exception if no values are passed.

```
public static int findMax(int...vals) {
    int max;
    // initialize max
    if (vals.length > 0) {
        max = vals[0];
    }
    else throw new RuntimeException("findMax requires at least one value");
    for (int d: vals) {
        if (d > max) max = d;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Or just

```
public static int findMax(int...vals) {
    int max = vals[0];
    for (int d: vals) {
        if (d > max) max = d;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to throw a `IllegalArgumentException` instead of a `RuntimeException`?

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be to use recursion:

```
private int getMaxInt(int... ints) {
        if (ints.length == 1) return ints[0];
        else return Math.max(ints[0], getMaxInt(Arrays.copyOfRange(ints, 1, ints.length)));
    }
```